# ffmpeg segment naming of rtsp surveillance stream HikVisions

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, filenames

I need to ensure unique segment names: Apparent POE cable defects, etc. around campus cause HikVision camera streams to require their ffmpeg daemons re-started once or twice or more times/day. (I am miles away from this campus for the most part, so I prefer a command line fix until the hardware fixes get applied.) When ffmpeg has to be restarted for a camera (by background bash script), I need the names of the new .mp4 segments positively not to be the same as any previous names.

Background bash process currently does fine to specify an acceptable ddHHMM style new starting name for the first segment after ffmpeg restart BUT after the first or sometime second or third segment is made, ffmpeg insists on future naming to default to an unacceptable YYYmmdd style and thus start to overwrite previous segments. I use `$(date +%d%H%M)` to obtain my acceptable date style.

I've tried a lot of different combinations of date codes and date embedding and both ssegment and segment muxers; also I know very little of the very complex realm that ffmpeg is normally used in outside of simple rtsp stream copy to .mp4 files.

ffmpeg command that is launched from inside bash script: `bash -c 'nohup ffmpeg -nostdin -stimeout 10000000 -rtsp_transport udp -i "rtsp://192.168.0.11:6554/Streaming/channels/101" -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -c:v libx264 -f ssegment -strftime 0 -segment_time 180 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 0 -increment_tc 1 -avoid_negative_ts 1 -c copy -flags +global_header /var/www/camera_streams/camera_east_driveway/"$(date +%d%H%M)"_%3d.mp4 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & '`

Can the segment naming pattern be carried forward indefinitely like I want? Honestly, I wonder if ffmpeg does not allow for my specific use case naming need?

(Yes, I know changing from udp to tcp can help, but I don't consider it to be the specific solid naming fix I'm hoping for right now. And I mention HikVision in case there is known frame encoding differences for them than other cameras)

Err msgs for ssegment muxer depend on whether -strftime is 0 (where I have to specify filename like `"$(date +%d%H%M)"_%3d.mp4)`
or 1 (where I have to specify filename like `"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"`)

where strftime is 0, the err is:

```
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x558d8618d2c0] Could not increment global timecode, no global timecode metadata found.
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x558d8618d2c0] Opening '/var/www/camera_streams/camera_south_driveway/220141_001.mp4' for writing
[mp4 @ 0x558d862f3d40] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x558d8618d2c0] Could not increment global timecode, no global timecode metadata found.
frame= 1434 fps=8.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:03:00.65 bitrate=N/A speed=1.02x    
video:21966kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 15.
```

where strftime is 1, the err is:

```
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x55cd7ae7e240] Opening '/var/www/camera_streams/camera_east_driveway/2022-07-22_01-23-48.mp4' for writing
Output #0, stream_segment,ssegment, to '/var/www/camera_streams/camera_east_driveway/%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 2560x1440, q=2-31, 6.25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x55cd7ae7e240] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x55cd7ae7e240] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55cd7ae959c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
[stream_segment,ssegment @ 0x55cd7ae7e240] Could not increment global timecode, no global timecode metadata found.
frame=   34 fps=7.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:25.59 bitrate=N/A speed=5.35x    
video:418kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 15.
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use a dedicated NVR software like motion or motioneye? Apart from that, have a look into the ffmpeg output instead of dumping it, it may contain far more useful information than any guesswork.

Comment: Thank you for the question!  I do remember doing a little research well over a year ago, maybe 5 years ago, into NVR software like those two.  I think I concluded that each of the options had some limiting inflexibility or did not encompass all of my vision (like Arduino interfacing)

Comment: "look into the ffmpeg output instead of dumping it" I assume you mean I should save more debug data that ffmpeg is capable of saving besides just what will render into scenery? Then I would investigate into if ffmpeg is giving errors that affect its file naming abilities at the beginning of a start or restart of the ffmpeg process?

Comment: yes. Instead of redirecting the output to `/dev/null`, write it to some file

Comment: "no global timecode metadata found." in ssegment muxer, -strftime 1, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"  (next to fetch err for  -strftime 0 and $(date +....)-%3d.mp4)

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1732933/edit) your question with additional information, instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I will resort to using the flag value `-strftime 0` so I get the `%3d` value in the file name of the specific segment file names produced after ffmpeg resets its %d to zeroes.  Catching that event with an inotifywait daemon, I will kill the ffmpeg process and start a new one with segment names that include that hour and minute.